# Update KML layer data in a Google Map without generating new file

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am developing a map using the Google Maps API in which specific regions are outlined with KML polygons, and have certain (numeric) values assigned to them. Those regions (provided by ID's) are defined in a KML file. For each region I want to show a specific amount, let's say, the number of inhabitants matching a certain query filter.

Now, the issue is that the polygon layers of the regions may be static - the shapes are always the same. However, I want to be able to update their associated values on the fly when new data is received, but currently these values are set within the KML file as well. Another problem is the polygon fill colors are based on these values, and these are defined in the KML too.

Currently the KML file looks something like this:

```
(...)
        <Placemark>
            <snippet></snippet>
            <description><![CDATA[<div class="googft-info-window">
<strong>Bedum</strong>: 62
</div>]]></description>
            <styleUrl>#Style2-polygon-1-map</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <Data name='ID'>
                    <value>005</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='REGION'>
                    <value>Bedum</value>
                </Data>
                <Data name='COUNT'>
                    <value>62</value>
                </Data>
            </ExtendedData><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>6.596591,53.348151 6.602419,53.341801 6.605422,53.341771 6.605371,53.339987 6.60532,53.338177 6.599265,53.336441 6.602115,53.33102 6.606643,53.331873 6.611121,53.330928 6.615495,53.32639 6.613943,53.324609 6.621189,53.315547 6.639193,53.315361 6.643511,53.309025 6.649538,53.309861 6.655538,53.309797 6.6305,53.27411 6.630323,53.273809 6.627348,53.26875 6.627296,53.266953 6.634608,53.260586 6.63595,53.25518 6.635872,53.252484 6.619341,53.250857 6.617894,53.25267 6.607407,53.252777 6.607412,53.252929 6.607458,53.254574 6.591365,53.256497 6.590857,53.258046 6.590566,53.258041 6.589825,53.258051 6.589813,53.258054 6.588051,53.25665 6.588296,53.257685 6.58973,53.26374 6.588933,53.263511 6.586707,53.262871 6.567202,53.262166 6.567276,53.264861 6.552241,53.26321 6.550815,53.26592 6.552312,53.270814 6.552459,53.271297 6.555579,53.27576 6.557394,53.28887 6.557443,53.289223 6.561151,53.31525 6.561241,53.315403 6.564299,53.320611 6.564414,53.320969 6.569219,53.335841 6.567742,53.336754 6.56789,53.342145 6.567969,53.342364 6.569515,53.346623 6.57557,53.34836 6.577071,53.348346 6.582923,53.344726 6.582978,53.344692 6.588958,53.343734 6.596591,53.348151</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark>
(...)
```

My question therefore is: how can I update the region values and their associated color, without having to generate an entire KML file server-side? Ideally I would only have to load the KML file once, only to outline the regions.
I'm looking for a solution like:

1. The KML file is being loaded once on page load and only contains the polygon coordinates and region ID's
2. Values associated to the regions are loaded through an AJAX callback (i.e. JSON formatted) and assigned to the regions
3. Polygon fill colors update themselves according to the assigned value (from light to dark red for example)
4. When user clicks on a region, pop out a balloon with region ID and associated value

Is this possible? Please let me know if I need to be more specific.

Comment: I would suggest FusionTables if using an experimental service is acceptable, otherwise a third party parser for KML like [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/)

Comment: As @geocodezip states, the Maps API KMLLayer does not appear to be the best way to solve your issue. I would look at alternate methods.

Comment: I see. I just tried using the geoxml3 parser, that seems to do what I want but it's pretty slow. Using Fusion Tables, if I'm right, I would have to generate a new table for each time new data is requested (I don't want to store all my data in Fusion Tables and query the FT API) so that doesn't seem to do it neither...